# Why does the regular expression not validate the website URL properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, url-validation

The following is the URL expression(regex) I'm using to validate website URL :

```
/(https?:\/\/)(www)?[A-Za-z0-9.\-@_~]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/[A-Za-z0-9\/_\-.~?&=]*)*/
```

My angular JS code implementation is as follows :

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <label>Website</label> 
        <input ng-model="schoolDetails.website" name="website" ng-change="editField()" type="url" ng-pattern="/(https?:\/\/)(www)?[A-Za-z0-9.\-@_~]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/[A-Za-z0-9\/_\-.~?&=]*)*/">
        <div ng-messages="schoolDetailsForm.website.$error">
           <div ng-message="pattern">Please enter a valid website</div>
       </div> 
</md-input-container>
```

Suppose I give valid URL `http://www.bharatividyapeeth.edu` it works fine.
If I give the invalid URL, `http://www.` the error message appears, but when I enter the invalid URL, `http://www.bharatividyapeeth` it doesn't show me the error message and accepts it as a valid URL.

Can some one please correct my code in order to properly validate the website URL?

Thanks.

Comment: last `*` in `(\/[A-Za-z0-9\/_\-.~?&=]*)*` will make the match successful even if it occurs `0` times

Comment: @rock321987:Would you please put up the correct regular expression as an answer? It would be of great help to me and I should accept it quickly as an answer.

Comment: Try [`ng-pattern="/^(https?:\/\/)(www\.)?(?!www\.)[A-Za-z0-9.@_~-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/[A-Za-z0-9\/_.~?&=-]*)*$/"`](https://regex101.com/r/eE3dT5/1)

Comment: i don't know why I was posting for `email verification`

Comment: `^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`

Comment: Modifying your regex a little bit `(https?:\/\/)(www)?[A-Za-z0-9\-@_~]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{2,5})?\.[A-Za-z0-9\/_\-~?&=]+`..It will work for most of cases but is not perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want a simpler `regex` for your task. So I am modifying your regex only. While this will work for most `URLs` but will also fail at some places

```
/https?:\/\/(www\.)?(?!www\.)([A-Za-z0-9\-@_~]+\.)[A-Za-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{2,5})?(\.[A-Za-z0-9\/_\-~?&=]+)*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be correct to me:

```js
var str = 'http://www.bharatividyapeeth.in'
var reg = /(http|https)(:\/\/)+?(w{3}(\.\w*\.))+(edu|com|co\.in|in)/gi;

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = str.match(reg)[0];
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am not good at regex. just tried something don't know its good or OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please test and see if this regex will work for you:

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})
```

This one will match the following:

```
http://www.bharatividyapeeth.edu
https://www.bharatividyapeeth.edu
www.bharatividyapeeth.edu
```

Will not match:

```
http://www.bharatividyapeeth
https://www.bharatividyapeeth
www.bharatividyapeeth
```

You can test here:

http://regexr.com/